# iPhone Tile View

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know how to create an icon tile layout similar to that of the Application tile view, where I can hold down an icon and sort them. This is also similar to the home screen of the Facebook application.

Is there a special UI control that I can use, or will I have to create this manually? If so, how would I do that?

Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe Hewitt's Three20 library has a "Launcher View" that does exactly what you need.

http://github.com/joehewitt/three20

Answer (score 0):

You could also use MyLauncher, if you prefer something other then the Three20 giant.

http://github.com/Jarada/myLauncher